# Unable to eliminate error after changing trap in .profile on macOS

Tags: bash, macos

In my `~/.profile` I am using this in FreeBSD 12.0 which works great:

```
prompt_title_command() {
    # use OSC escape sequence to set window/tab title
    printf "\e]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME} \u2014 ${PWD} \u2014 ${BASH_COMMAND}\a"
}
trap prompt_title_command DEBUG
```

This sets the window/tab title. The `\u2014` is the em-dash unicode character.

Then I copied it and tried using it in macOS 10.14.3 but would get these errors:

```
-bash: printf: missing unicode digit for \u

-bash: printf: missing unicode digit for \u
```

Even though I would get this error, the unicode character prints as expected in the title.

This only happens when opening a new tab or window.

I then changed the previous code to use two normal dashes instead of the unicode em-dash:

```
prompt_title_command() {
    # use OSC escape sequence to set window/tab title
    printf "\e]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME} -- ${PWD} -- ${BASH_COMMAND}\a"
}
trap prompt_title_command DEBUG
```

But I still get the same errors and can't get rid of them no matter what I try unless comment out the `trap` line.

Versions:

- GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (amd64-portbld-freebsd12.0)
- GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0)

This idea comes from:
https://mg.pov.lt/blog/bash-prompt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the trap to after `PS1` is set eliminated the problem. I don't know why that makes a difference.